# Need to Change the Textbox Value to Indian Currency Format (On Text changed event)

Tags: c#, wpf, cultureinfo

I had written one Event which Allows only Integer Values to the Textbox.

Now My Additional requirement is I need to the change Textbox Integer value to Indian Currency Format (I need to achieve this at OnTextchanged Event in WPF)

```
   private void validateTextInteger(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-IN", false).NumberFormat;
        nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)nfi.Clone();
        nfi.CurrencySymbol = "";
        Exception X = new Exception();
        TextBox T = (TextBox)sender;
        try
        {
            if (T.Text.Trim() != "-")
            {
                int x = int.Parse(T.Text);
                T.Text = string.Format(nfi, "{0:C0}", x);
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            try
            {
                int CursorIndex = T.SelectionStart - 1;
                T.Text = T.Text.Remove(CursorIndex, 1);
                //Align Cursor to same index
                T.SelectionStart = CursorIndex;
                T.SelectionLength = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just add `xml:lang="en-IN"` to your `UserControl` or `Window` opening tag.

Comment: All of this could be replaced with `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Value StringFormat=\{0:C\}}"/>`

Comment: Hi Its not Working and I am getting compile Time error

in  Text="{Binding Value StringFormat=\{0:C\}}"

Comment: Post your xaml then I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I achieved it By using the below code

```
    private void validateTextInteger(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        NumberFormatInfo nfi = new CultureInfo("en-IN", false).NumberFormat;
        nfi = (NumberFormatInfo)nfi.Clone();
        nfi.CurrencySymbol = "";
        Exception X = new Exception();
        TextBox T = (TextBox)sender;
        try
        {
            if (T.Text.Trim() != "-")
            {
                var val = T.Text.Trim();
                int x=0;
                val = val.Replace(",", "");
                if (!(val.Contains(',')))
                {
                     x = int.Parse(val);
                }
                string  s  = string.Format(nfi, "{0:C0}", x);
                T.Text = s.Trim();
                T.SelectionStart = T.Text.Length ;
                T.SelectionLength = 0;
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            try
            {
                int CursorIndex = T.SelectionStart - 1;
                T.Text = T.Text.Remove(CursorIndex, 1);
                //Align Cursor to same index
                T.SelectionStart = T.Text.Length;
                T.SelectionLength = 0;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { 
            }
        }
    }
```